# htaccess file works on server, doesn't work locally

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, config

I've been searching around and trying all sorts of different approaches, but I can't seem to figure out what's wrong.

I have the following piece of .htaccess code:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
IndexIgnore */*
# Turn on the RewriteEngine
RewriteEngine On
#  Rules
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

It works fine on the production server, so that insinuates that the config file is set up okay there. 
I'm trying to develop for this site locally though, and there I get 404 errors saying that the file does not exist when I go to localhost/example/login (which corresponds with domain.com/login).

I have tried different settings, setting AllowOverride All, checking if mod_rewrite is enabled in phpinfo(); and what not. But I can't seem to figure out what's wrong.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

check out if mod_rewrite is enabled. Don`t forget to restart apache.
Check your virtualhosts, is allow override is on?

Comment: I'll simply quote this:

I have tried different settings, setting AllowOverride All, checking if mod_rewrite is enabled in phpinfo(); and what not. But I can't seem to figure out what's wrong.

I did try to test if I could mess up the server by setting incorrect values in httpd.conf and restart it; to see if it would come on again. It didn't, so I have the right file as well... Any other suggestions?

Comment: Check the name of .htaccess file :)
May be your virtual hosts links to another directory, add one more virtual hosts to another directory and add htaccess in there.

Comment: I've never added virtual hosts on my local development machine. I'll have a quick look!

Comment: You were right; I didn't have the allowOverride on properly. I apparently have two different <Directory> tags in my httpd.conf and only did a search for AllowOverride and changed the first one. That one wasn't the right one for my development folder.